# Listening and firing events with Javascript and maybe jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

In my JavaScript and Flex applications, users often perform actions that I want other JavaScript code on the page to listen for.  For example, if someone adds a friend.  I want my JavaScript app to then call something like `triggerEvent("addedFriend", name);`.  Then any other code that was listening for the `"addedFriend"` event will get called along with the name.

Is there a built-in JavaScript mechanism for handling events?  I'm ok with using jQuery for this too and I know jQuery makes extensive use of events.  But with jQuery, it seems that its event mechanism is all based around elements.  As I understand, you have to tie a custom event to an element.  I guess I can do that to a dummy element, but my need has nothing to do with DOM elements on a webpage.

Should I just implement this event mechanism myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options:

- jQuery **does** allow you to do this with objects not associated with the document. An example is provided below.
- If you're not already using jQuery on your page, then adding it is probably overkill. There are other libraries designed for this. The pattern you are referring to is called **PubSub** or **Publish/Subscribe**.
- Implement it yourself, as you've suggested, since this is not difficult if you're looking only for basic functionality.

jQuery example:

```
var a = {};
jQuery(a).bind("change", function () {
    alert("I changed!");
});
jQuery(a).trigger("change");
```

Comment: Of course, if you include JQuery anyway, I'm sure you'll find other places where you'll find it *very* useful.  You also get the benefit of using code that's been tried and tested in production environments by countless developers, whereas your own implementation may be riddled with some bugs. Additionally, computers are getting faster and faster, so the few millisecond pageload benefit of implementing yourself isn't that great in comparison to the faster implemented few lines of code in @Box9's example.

Comment: @jmort253, yes jQuery is a fine option. I offered the other alternatives though since the requirement for DOM manipulation may be minimal, or even non existent (not sure how flex works)

Comment: I am actually already using jQuery, I guess it bothered me that I'd have to bind the PubSub mechanism to an element which really had nothing to do with the event process.  It bothers me now that I have to do the same to a dummy object I have to create, but it bothers me less so :).  I'll use this solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement such using MVVM pattern with [knockjs](http://knockoutjs.com/) library.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an element, and use jquery events on it. 
It can be just a global variable, doesn't even have to be connected to the DOM. 
That way you accomplish your task easily and without any extra libs.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it possible to bind onchange events in addition to click events?  For instance, if addFriend is called and modifies a list on the page, you could bind the change event to then invoke additional functionality.

```
  $('#addFriendButton').click( function() {
      // modify the #friendList list
  });



  $('#friendList').change( function() {
      myOtherAction();
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is total Host independent, no need for jQuery or dom in this case!

```
function CustomEvents(){
 //object holding eventhandlers
 this.handlers_ = {}; 
}
//check if the event type does not exist, create it. 
//then push new callback in array.
CustomEvents.prototype.addEventListner = function (type, callBack){
 if (!this.handlers_[type]) this.handlers_[type] = [];
  this.handlers_[type].push(callBack);
}

CustomEvents.prototype.triggerEvent = function (type){
 //trigger all handlers attached to events
 if (!this.handlers_[type]) return; 
 for (var i=0, handler; handler = this.handlers_[type][i]; i++)
 {
  //call handler function and supply all the original arguments of this function
  //minus the first argument which is the type of the event itself
  if (typeof handler === "function") handler.apply(this,arguments.slice(1));
 }

}
//delete all handlers to an event
CustomEvents.prototype.purgeEventType = function(type){
 return delete this.handlers_[type];
}
```

test:

```
var customEvents = new CustomEvents();
customEvents.addEventListner("event A", function(arg){alert('Event A with arguments' + arg);));
customEvents.triggerEvent("event A", "the args");
```

**EDIT** added arguments passing